# Generating a Random Type 1 UUID from a Unix Timestamp for use with Cassandra

Tags: java, scala, cassandra, uuid

Is it possible to generate a Type 1 UUID in Scala/Java (for use in Cassandra) from a particular Unix timestamp such that it could be used to obtain range slices of records, and individual records from a table.  The following result seem to indicate it may be possible.

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.utils._

var td = new DateTime(2003,1,1,0,0)
val time_millis = td.getMillis()
val lower =  UUIDs.startOf(time_millis)
val upper =  UUIDs.endOf(time_millis)

println(lower.getLeastSignificantBits())  #  9187201950435737472
println(lower.getMostSignificantBits())   # -545498504376938025
println(upper.getLeastSignificantBits())  # -9187201950435737471
println(upper.getMostSignificantBits())   # -545455558998945321
```

**Background** (in case there is a better way to solve the problem).

I would like to batch import a few thousand records of vehicles into a into a Cassandra database. The date included column contains the day on which the vehicles were added to the original database (VCA) and typically no more than few hundred are added on a particular day, which seems to indicate the entropy available in a timeuuid may be sufficient for this problem; namely the mac address, hours, seconds,...,100 nanoseconds and random parts.

Example queries that I need to perform

```
SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE manufacturer = 'BMW';
SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE manufacturer = 'BMW' AND id = a8bb5800-694c-11d7-8080-808080808080;
SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE manufacturer = 'BMW' AND id < a8bb5800-694c-11d7-8080-808080808080 AND id >= cb59c000-1c26-11d6-8080-808080808080;
```

The table schema in CQL.

```
CREATE TABLE vehicles (
  id                 timeuuid,
  manufacturer       text,
  model              text,
  transmission       text,
  description        text,
  engine_capacity    double,
  fuel_type          text,
  metric_urban       double,
  metric_extra_urban double,
  metric_combined    double,
  co2_g_per_km       double,
  euro_standard      int,
  noise              double,
  co                 double,
  hc_nox             double,
  hc                 double,
  nox                double,
  particulates       double,
  date_included      timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (manufacturer, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id ASC);
```

The companion manufacturers table

```
SELECT * from manufacturers;

CREATE TABLE manufacturers (
  id                 uuid,
  manufacturer       text,
  years              set<int>
  PRIMARY KEY (manufacturer, id)
);
```

Comment: Your title is confusing with word `random`. [Version 1 UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_.28MAC_address_.26_date-time.29) is based on date-time and MAC address, with only a few of the 128 bits being random. [Version 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) is the type that is nearly entirely random.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it is possible to do that in theory.  However, there are no standard Java APIs that allow you to specify the "current time" when generation a UUID.

This is not how type 1 UUIDs are intended to be used.  (Not withstanding Cassandra's ability to select "timeuuid" values based on the time!)  The embedded timestamp is a part of a scheme for guaranteeing uniqueness ... nothing more.  If you start artificially generating type 1 UUIDs for a different time than the current one, you have the (theoretical) problem that your "new" UUIDs may actually be identical to UUIDs that were genuinely created on that machine and at that time; i.e. your UUIDs are no longer unique.

If I was doing this, I would generate UUIDs the normal way and store the timestamps in a separate field.

---

**UPDATE**

You might be able to adapt "https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-uuid-generator" to do what you want.  (Hint: write a tricky "timestamp synchronizer").  But I still think this is a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks @stephen. I ended up using a timestamp and a Type 4 UUID as you suggested and a created a new lookup table indexed by id, to find parameters(manufacturer, date included etc.) to query the main table from an id. Given that the imports are going to be batch operations duplication/multiple sources of truth shouldn't be too much of an issue, and I believe it is idiomatic given that a similar strategy is used in modelling relations in Cassandra.

Comment: I definitely agree that extracting date-time from a UUID is an abuse of the UUID’s purpose. Such "cleverness" often leads to trouble. But if you were to insist on doing that, at least check [the few bits of the UUID that identify its version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Variants_and_versions) to verify it is indeed [Version 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_.28MAC_address_.26_date-time.29) containing a date-time. All versions have 128 bits and can be substituted for one another, so do not assume a UUID is Version 1.